# Django taggit aggregation query to return count per tag

Tags: python, django, django-queryset, django-taggit

I am using Django 3.2 and django-taggit 1.4

I have a model like this:

```
class Meal(models.Model):
    # some fields
    is_cooked = models.Boolean()
    tags = TaggitManager()
```

I am trying to generate a dictionary keyed by tag name and value of the number of times the tag appears - but only for meals that have the `is_cooked` flag set to True.

I have tried the following:

```
pks = list(Meal.objects.filter(is_cooked=True))
ct = ContentType.objects.get_for_model(Meal)
b=TaggedItem.objects.filter(content_type=ct, object_id__in=pks).annotate(num_times=Count('tag__name'))
```

This is not returning the expected results (and I expect that it might be hitting the DB several times because of so many lookups - but I don't want to get distracted by premature optimisation concerns.

What am I doing wrong, and how do I get the count of Tags per tag?

**[[Edit]]**

Here are the results from running the query above:

```
<QuerySet [<TaggedItem: Meal One tagged with rice>, <TaggedItem: Meal Two tagged with chips>, <TaggedItem: Meal Three tagged with curry>, <TaggedItem: Meal Four tagged with royalty>, <TaggedItem: Meal Five tagged with rice>, <TaggedItem: Meal Six tagged with chips>]>


>>> b[0].num_times
1
```

Comment: hi, what is the unexpected output?

Comment: @jspcal: please see edits

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can filter the annotation with:

```
from django.db.models import Count, Q
from taggit.models import Tag

Tag.objects.annotate(
    nmeal=Count('meal', filter=Q(meal__is_cooked=True))
)
```

The `Tag` objects that arise from thsi queryset will have an extra attribute `.nmeals` that contains the number of *cooked* meals.

If you only want to retrieve `Tag` objects where there is at least one related cooked meal, you can work with:

```
from django.db.models import Count, Q
from taggit.models import Tag

Tag.objects.filter(
    meal__is_cooked=True
).annotate(
    nmeal=Count('meal')
)
```

Comment: How does the Tag object know what `'meal'` is ??? (what kind of magic is this) :D

Comment: @HomunculusReticulli: the `TaggableManager` basically works as a sort of `ManyToManyField`, so we can query to a certain model that has a `TaggableManager`.

Comment: I'm guessing it does a kind of 'related_name' behind the scenes then. This is nothing short of magic! What is the mapping between the model name and the name that the `Tag` object expects? Would it for example 'mangle' the name of a class like `MySuperDoopaClass` ? What would I need to pass to Tag object for the query to still work?

Comment: @HomunculusReticulli: if you have two models with the same name (but for example in different apps), it will raise an exception about a `related_name`: clash:app1.Title.tags: (fields.E304) Reverse accessor for 'app1.Title.tags' clashes with reverse accessor for 'app2.Title.tags'.
 HINT: Add or change a related_name argument to the definition for 'app1.Title.tags' or 'app2.Title.tags'.

Comment: @HomunculusReticulli: if there are two with the same name, you can thus work with `TaggableManager(related_name='other_related_name')`.

Comment: The advantage is thus that if you know the other end of the relation (here `Meal`.) with a `Tag`, you can directly use the `related_name`, and thus not filter by content type, etc.

Comment: I'm trying to work out the casing of the field name passed to the `Count` function. For instance, if my model is `SomeFancyName` - what do I pass to the `Count` function? 'SomeFancyName', 'somefancyname' or 'some_fancy_name' ?

Comment: @HomunculusReticulli: it will work with the `related_name` parameter if set, if not set, it will use `modelname` in lowercase and without underscores, so for a `Meal` model it is `meal`, for `TwoWords`, it is `twowords`.