# django-taggit get number of posts that use a particular tag

Tags: django, django-queryset, django-taggit

What I want to do is to get the number of posts for a particular tag, kind of like how Instagram and Twitter do, I found some solutions
[this](https://github.com/jazzband/django-taggit/issues/203) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68627137/django-taggit-aggregation-query-to-return-count-per-tag). I want to clarify if this is the only way to achieve what I want. Wouldn't it be bad to calculate the number of posts every time someone tries to access a tag?

So, I created a custom tag by following these [instructions](https://django-taggit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/custom_tagging.html), and have added a num_posts field.

```
class Hashtag(TagBase):
num_posts = models.IntegerField(default=0, blank=False, null=False)

class Meta:
    verbose_name = _("Tag")
    verbose_name_plural = _("Tags")
```

So, how do I increase the num_posts value whenever a new post uses this tag? Or when a post creates a new tag, automatically assign the value of 1 to num_posts. I tried to look into the source code of django-taggit, specifically the TaggableManager, to see if I can override something there and get the intended results. So far I was not able to do anything. Can someone please give me some assistance?

Edit:
I did find something [here](https://django-taggit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/custom_tagging.html#custom-tag), though I have some doubts, like suppose I try to add 3 different tags to a model and wish to have different values for my extra parameters(each parameter with a different value). How am I supposed to do that?

```
my_food.tags.add("tag_name1", "tag_name2", tag_kwargs={"my_field":3})
```

The line above seems to add the same value. Also, when I remove a tag, how do I then pass the value of tag_kwargs, because it throws an error right now.

```
TypeError: _TaggableManager.remove() got an unexpected keyword argument 'tag_kwargs'
```

Comment: Can you please add the *full* traceback?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem never mind, I solved it on my own. Thank you anyway.